# Mule - How to arrange a flow which should only run once before a Quartz scheduled flow

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz scheduled flow which should only run once an initial flow has completed. The initial flow sets up data which must be present in a file for the quartz scheduled process to succeed. However, the quartz process starts and the initial process never starts. I only want the initial to run once so I don't want it to be run in the quartz flow.

```
     <!-- Needs to run only once -->
      <flow name="InitialJob">
       <component ....
     </flow>

    <!-- Depends on InitialJob -->
    <flow name="ScheduledProcess">
          <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Schd" 
            cronExpression="0 */5 * * * ?" jobName="doIt" 
            repeatInterval="0">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
         </quartz:inbound-endpoint>

         <!-- I don't want to put InitialJob  here, 
           I only want it to run once
              -->
        <flow-ref name="PerformJob"/>
   </flow>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? How can I arrange the flows to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I answered the question, but can you give more precision about the data being setup?
It looks like your application will try to self-configure itself on start-up. Even though your problem as described can be solved, there may be other ways of handling your "setup data in some file" issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two flows, one which will be triggered periodically but disabled on start-up and one that will set-up your data and activate the periodic flow. Something like:

```
    <!-- Will run periodically once started -->
    <flow name="PeriodicJob" initialState="stopped">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="PeriodicJob" cronExpression="* * * * * ?" repeatInterval="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <flow-ref name="PerformJob"/>
    </flow>

    <!-- Will run once on start-up and activate PeriodJob -->
    <flow name="InitialJobRunOnce">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="InitialJobRunOnce" repeatInterval="0" repeatCount="0" startDelay="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <expression-component doc:name="Activate period job"><![CDATA[app.registry.PeriodicJob.start();]]></expression-component>
    </flow>
```

Your initial flow will run once on start-up, but this "run a flow once" approach have some limits. If your application restart, the initial flow will run again - though this can be somehow mitigated by adding some logic to your initial flow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's what I did after I found a post on the Mule web site Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
In your initial flow try to start the quartz flow like this`<expression-component>
    app.registry.yourflowName.start();
  </expression-component>`

Then in after quartz flow is finished try to stop the initial flow with below script:`<expression-component>
    app.registry.yourflowName.stop();
  </expression-component>`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that.

Comment: How do you know when the initial flow is complete? Also, once the quartz flow starts and the initial flow has stopped once, it will also mean trying to stop the flow every time once the quartz scheduler cycle has completed. This is similar to running the initial job in the scheduler

Comment: You can wrap it up with if condition.

Comment: It did not work as I was hoping. It still tests multiple times needlessly after the quartz scheduler. In which case I can simply call the initial job following just after the scheduler.